# Javascript form validation matching emails and zip code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get form validation working for a homework assignment but my teacher is essentially useless. I'm supposed to follow this website's (https://jqueryvalidation.org/) documentation to create a form that checks for the e-mails to match and also to have a zip code, and I've tried a few different methods to get this working so far. The only thing that's working right now is the `js/jquery.validate.js` file that I downloaded from the website, but it currently only checks for a valid e-mail, not that the confirmation e-mail matches nor for a valid zip code. So, what I've tried is using a local script to add rules and messages for those two things, but they don't seem to work. I've also tried doing it in an external .js file (I'll post the code to that below the .html code below) but that also fails to work.

````
======Index.html:======

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Join Email List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="email_list.css">

</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Please join our email list</h1>
        <h4>* denotes required field</h4>
        <form id="email_form" name="email_form" action="join.html" method="get">
            <label for="email">Email Address:*</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br>

            <label for="email_confirm">Re-enter Email:*</label>
            <input type="text" id="email_confirm" name="email_confirm" required><br>

            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"><br>

            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name"><br>

            <label for="zip">5-Digit Zip Code:*</label>
            <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" required><br>

            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="submit" id="join" name="join" value="Join our List">
            <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"><br>
        </form>
    </section>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/validate.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( "#email_form" ).validate({
  rules: {
  
    email_confirm: {
      equalTo: "#email"
    }
    
    zip: {
        minlength: 5
        maxlength: 5
    }
  }
  
  messages: {
    email_confirm: {
        equalTo: "E-mail must match."
        }
    zip: {
        minlength: "Zip code must be 5 digits.",
        maxlength: "Zip code must be 5 digits."
        }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>```



========js/Validate.js:=======

$().ready(function() {
    $("email_form").validate();
        rules: {
            
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
            
            email_confirm: {
                equalTo: "#email"
            }
            
            zip: {
                minlength: 5,
            }
        }
            
        messages: { 
        
            email: {
                required: "Please enter an e-mail",
                email: "Please enter a valid e-mail",
            }
            
            email_confirm: {
                equalTo: "Your e-mails must match"
            }
            
            zip: {
                minlength: "Please enter a valid 5-digit zip code"
            }
        
        
        }
}
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script in the HTML has errors in validate()

Try this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Join Email List</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="email_list.css"> -->

</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Please join our email list</h1>
        <h4>* denotes required field</h4>
        <form id="email_form" name="email_form" action="join.html" method="get">
            <label for="email">Email Address:*</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br>

            <label for="email_confirm">Re-enter Email:*</label>
            <input type="text" id="email_confirm" name="email_confirm" required><br>

            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"><br>

            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name"><br>

            <label for="zip">5-Digit Zip Code:*</label>
            <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" required><br>

            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="submit" id="join" name="join" value="Join our List">
            <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"><br>
        </form>
    </section>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.2/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/validate.js"></script> -->
    <script>
    $( "#email_form" ).validate({
  rules: {
  
    email_confirm: {
      equalTo: "#email:checked"
    },
    
    zip: {
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 5
    }
  },
  
  messages: {
    email_confirm: {
        equalTo: "E-mail must match."
        },
    zip: {
        minlength: "Zip code must be 5 digits.",
        maxlength: "Zip code must be 5 digits."
        }
}});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I fixed the syntax errors in the script tag also I added the script cdn for the jquery validation ==>

Comment: Thanks much! It's working great and I understand now why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute type and pattern to invalidate html elements,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern,

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a necessary script and made some mistakes. You'll find the corrected version below with comments. Don't forget to delete those.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Join Email List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="email_list.css">  
    <!-- this stylsheet is necessary for styling of the warnings -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Please join our email list</h1>
        <h4>* denotes required field</h4>
        <form id="email_form" name="email_form" action="join.html" method="get">
            <label for="email">Email Address:*</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br>

            <label for="email_confirm">Re-enter Email:*</label>
            <input type="text" id="email_confirm" name="email_confirm" required><br>

            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"><br>

            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name"><br>

            <label for="zip">5-Digit Zip Code:*</label>
            <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" required><br>

            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="submit" id="join" name="join" value="Join our List">
            <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"><br>
        </form>
    </section>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script> // script missing
    <script>
    $("#email_form").validate({  // # missing
        rules: {

            email: {
                required: true
            }, // comma missing

            email_confirm: {
                equalTo: "#email"
            }, // comma missing

            zip: {
                minlength: 5, // comma missing
            }
        }, // comma missing

        messages: {

            email: {
                required: "Please enter an e-mail",
                email: "Please enter a valid e-mail", // comma missing
            },

            email_confirm: {
                equalTo: "Your e-mails must match"
            }, // comma missing

            zip: {
                minlength: "Please enter a valid 5-digit zip code"
            }


        }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```